# NSTextAttachment Kerning

Tags: ios, uitextview, textkit, kerning, nstextattachment

I'm trying to change the horizontal position of a NSTextAttachment image within a UITextView. I've tried setting

```
[attributedString setAttributes:@{NSKernAttributeName:@(1.5)} range:NSMakeRange(0, 1)];
```

This simply makes the attachment disappear while giving me the appropriate kerning space. I've also tried changing the origin x-coordinate in

```
- (CGRect)attachmentBoundsForTextContainer:(NSTextContainer *)textContainer proposedLineFragment:(CGRect)lineFrag glyphPosition:(CGPoint)position characterIndex:(NSUInteger)charIndex
```

This has no effect on the horizontal position of the attachment. 
Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

You can set  horizontal position of a NSTextAttachment image by  textAttachment.bounds  properties.

```
NSTextAttachment *textAttachment = [[NSTextAttachment alloc] init];
NSURLRequest *imageRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"YourImageURL"] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataElseLoad timeoutInterval:60];
NSData *urlData=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:imageRequest returningResponse:nil error:nil];
UIImage * image = [UIImage imageWithData:urlData];
if (image != nil) {
textAttachment.image = image;
} else {
textAttachment.image =[UIImage imageNamed:@"YourPlaceHolderImageName"];
            }
textAttachment.bounds =  CGRectMake(0,-4, textAttachment.image.size.height, textAttachment.image.size.width);
```

Comment: This adjusts the vertical position.